# What is pseudogap phase in high $T_c$ cuprates?

Tags: thermodynamics, condensed-matter, superconductivity

In high temperature cuprates phase diagram there are different phases namely pseudogap and strange metal. Why do we call them pseudogap and strange metal regime?

Comment: Strange metal is the regime in the phase space where the conventional Fermi liquid picture breaks down due to the strong correlations between interacting electrons. The pseudogap has to deal with the dropping of the antiferromagnetic Mott insulator. Which upon dopping becomes a superconductor.

Comment: @felix what's the reason for calling it as a pseudogap regime?

Answer (score 1):

Before addressing these issues, a very important point: we do not know what are the origins of the pseudogap nor the strange metal behavior. We know the effects, not the causes. Whoever says otherwise is trying to push his own theory. Having said that...

As far as I know, the pseudogap in cuprates was first proposed in a paper about NRM of YBCO [Alloul et al. PRL 63, 1700 (1989)]. The idea is that the Knight-shift of the NMR line, a feature associated with the formation of Cooper pairs in superconductors, appears at at temperature higher that $T_c$ and indicates a depletion of states at the Fermi surface. A total depletion of states at the Fermi-surface is the definition of a gap (forbidden energy region between two bands -- such as valence and conduction bands in semiconductors). Here, the data suggests a partial depletion of states, hence a "pseudogap".

Why do you have this partial depletion of states? We don't know. Several ideas have been put forward (antiferromagnetic fluctuations, pre-formed Cooper pairs without phase coherence, loop-currents between copper and oxygen atoms, and more). No definite proof for any of the ideas exists so-far.

And now for something completely different. The strange metal.

At low temperatures, a metal should follow the Fermi-liquid theory proposed by Landau in the 1950s. In this theory, the low temperature electrical resistivity increases with the square of the temperature. In cuprates, we observe that it increases linearly with temperature. Hence the "strange" metal. And, once more, we don't know why.